# Create mandatory token in ANTLR

Tags: go, antlr, antlr4

I'm just getting into ANTLR. I'm trying to create a simple hello world ANTLR. My goal is to make "Hello world" a mandatory string. I'm thus expecting an input of "Hello" to be considered invalid, and it giving me an error stating it expects a "world" token.

Edit: Please note that I do want "hello" and "world" to be separate tokens (consider them to be keywords) so that I can easily identify them separately.

I have the below helloworld.g4:

```
grammar helloworld;

WHITESPACE: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
HELLO : 'Hello' ;
WORLD : 'world' ;

start : HELLO WORLD EOF ;
```

I have the following main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "test/parser"

    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
)

const rule = `Hello`

type testListener struct {
    *parser.BasehelloworldListener
}

func main() {
    // Setup the input
    is := antlr.NewInputStream(rule)

    // Create the Lexer
    lexer := parser.NewhelloworldLexer(is)
    // Read all tokens

    for {
        t := lexer.NextToken()
        if t.GetTokenType() == antlr.TokenEOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s (%q)\n",
            lexer.SymbolicNames[t.GetTokenType()],
            t.GetText())
    }

    // Finally parse the expression
    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer,
        antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)

    // Create the Parser
    p := parser.NewhelloworldParser(stream)

    // Finally parse the expression
    antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk(&testListener{}, p.Start())
}
```

I'm building a Go parser, and testing the outcome with the below command:

```
antlr -Dlanguage=Go -o parser helloworld.g4 && go run main.go
```

Which outputs:

```
HELLO ("Hello")
line 1:5 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting 'Hello'
```

I'm wondering what I can do to give me an output, stating "world" is an expected token after "hello". It shouldn't expect another "Hello", it should expect "world" and then an EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the lexer you've defined 2 separate tokens, so the lexer has no issues with the input `"Hello"`.

If that hello-token should always be followed by `"world"`, then you must include that in the token:

```
HELLO : 'Hello' ' '+ 'world';
```

If you invoke the parser rule `start`, that *will* result in an error. This is usually the way to enforce the presence of the `WORLD` token (in the parser), not in the lexer.

#### EDIT

You're consuming all tokens, and then feed this "consumed lexer" to the parser. Skip the printing of the tokens, or re-initialize the lexer after printing the tokens.

This should do:

```golang
func main() {
    is := antlr.NewInputStream(`Hello`)

    lexer := parser.NewhelloworldLexer(is)

    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer,
        antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)

    p := parser.NewhelloworldParser(stream)

    antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk(&testListener{}, p.Start())
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Perhaps I should clarify in my question a bit more: I do want the "hello" and "world" to remain separate tokens, so I can easily identify them separately.

Comment: My answer will still be the same: when you have them as separate tokens, you cannot tell inside the lexer that there is a missing `WORLD` token. Nor should the lexer be responsible for that: that's the parser's work (which it already does). If you parse (so not just tokenise!) `"Hello"`, you will see an error appear.

Comment: Ah, that explains what part I'm missing. What I'm doing in my main.go is purely tokenising the string (identifying the found tokens), whereas the parser is responsible for making sure the tokens are placed correctly. I've updated the question with my new main.go and slightly changed grammar file, including updated issue. Perhaps you could point out what I'm doing wrong now. Almost there.

Comment: You call the parser after lexing, which leaves lexer and input stream at the end of file for the parser. If you need to print out the token stream, do so after calling the parser.